# css browser hack using media query for IE10/11 not working

Tags: html, css

I found this css query on a few sites so I could target users who are browsing on IE11:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

I implemented it like so:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif
}

#browser_warning{
    display: none;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #browser_warning{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

and the html is simply:

```
<body>  
    <div id="browser_warning">
        <h1>Stop using IE11, FFS!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

but it's just not working - the display stays as `none` even when I run it in IE11. What could be preventing this from working? I've tried several alternatives including those at [Targeting IE 11 in css not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485760/targeting-ie-11-in-css-not-working)

There are no inline css stylings and the only parent element is the body. There are no `div` styles in the css stylesheet. I'm running IE11 but using Visual Studio IIS Express to test it - although I can't see how that would matter, it's still IE11 parsing the html and css.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Targeting IE 11 in css not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485760/targeting-ie-11-in-css-not-working)

Comment: Nope, I've just tried the three alternatives on that answer and it still doesn't work. I just can't see why it's failing!

Comment: IE11 was running in compatibility mode. SMH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple:

**Check that IE11 is not running the domain in compatibility mode!**

I spent well over an hour on this and it also solved lots of other styling issues I was having.

In fact it fixed the issue that required me to have a browser warning running in the first place :D :D

It'd be sad if it wasn't so funny...